# How to clean '/dev/sdx' cache?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, ssd, sata, umount

I'm facing a problem in my ubuntu system, as it is for testing, I usually issue the command:

```
echo "scsi add-single-device 0 0 0 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

I'm just using the `ata1` port.

When I finish the tests I just issue:

```
echo "scsi remove-single-device 0 0 0 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

But, as I started using ata commands, this process no longer works, as it attached to the system.

For example,

**Before:**

This commands always returned the `/dev/sdb` mounted, and the other command simply unmounted the drive, not attaching it to the system.

**Now:**

This commands I mentioned, seem to work, but continue to fill the cache with the next letter for every drive I test, say:

First test: `/dev/sdb`

Second test: `/dev/sdc`

and so on until I run out of letters because the system cannot issue past the `dev/sdz`

Can someone tell me how to flush the cache or how to workaround this issue?

I would REALLY appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem with the actual "cache".

I had a piece of code that was letting a file descriptor open in each drive test until the program filled up all remaining spaces for fd allocation. The error was in the python call `open()` as it was opening it with the argument `os.O_RDWR` instead of `os.O_RDONLY.`

`os.O_RDWR` was letting all file descriptors opened after issuing an ATA command. After changing it to `os.O_RDONLY` the memory buffer was readable and the file descriptor was closed properly.

Hope this helps anybody in a pinch.